# Strange output of bash script

Tags: bash, cron, output

I have bash script successfully running on CentOS 6 as cron

```
sh /a/mem1.sh >/a/mem1.txt; if [ -s /a/mem1.txt ] ; then mail -s "Server Low Memory" < /a/mem1.txt server@example.com ; fi
```

but under CentOS 7 it also successfully works as cron - but issues a strange 3-line additional output

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

So I receive two emails - one with normal script output as should be and another email with the strange outputs as above

I checked line-by-line the script commands inside - everything works without any errors or warnings.
Google did not help a lot.
Thanks in advance for a hint what it could be and how to solve it.

Comment: Is cron sending the second email or is `mail` sending it?

Comment: @anubhava thanks, tried, did not help - seems idea from Etan Reisner is closer but I need to understand a syntax as below

Answer (score 2):

Something is running `tput` in that script (presumably to colorize output when it can) and CentOS 7 clearly has no `TERM` value set in the cron environment so `tput` is complaining about it.

Either remove the calls to `tput` from the script or set a value for `TERM` for that process via cron or add the `-T` flag to the calls to force a particular term type.

Comment: Or rewrite the script to only use tput if stdout is a terminal, as it should have been doing in the first place.

Comment: Your explanation is very logic and I feel a solution somewhere here.
But it's still specific for me how to set TERM or -T flag syntax.
I have such commands in script like
`free=$(free -mt | grep Total | awk '{print $4}')`
and 
`vmstat 2 -n 1`
and
`ps aux > /tmp/`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`_ps-aux`
How to rewrite them ?

Comment: None of those commands uses `tput` anywhere. Is that the entire script? Does the script run any other scripts? Does the script source shell startup files?

Comment: Please, look the list of commands I use there - I've edited my question above

Comment: I can just add TERM or -T for every of them for expirement.
Just show me a syntax example

Comment: `tput` is not used in that script directly. None of the standard system commands use it either (i.e. not `grep`, `awk`, `free`, `ps`, `sort`, `head`, etc.). It is possible that `sar` or `mpstat` uses it but I find that unlikely. Does `/a/memtop` use it?

Comment: You pointed me to right direction. I found only
`mem=$(/usr/local/bin/memtop -n 15)` and `echo "${mem}"` ;
cause it. All other OK.
Thanks for any idea how to try it with TERM or -T flag

Comment: Those are both workarounds. The **correct** fix is to only run `tput` when standard output is a terminal (the `test`/`[` command's `-t` test) and/or not run it at all. So prefer fixing that `memtop` script to working around the problem.